# Area of the region bounded by different functions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, area

[image]

Diagram above shows a graph of curve $y=g(x)$ and a straight line $y=f(x)$. Given that $\int_{0}^{h}g(x)dx=6$. Find the area in term of $m$ for the region bounded by $y$-axis, $y=g(x)$ and $y=f(x)$

My attempt:

The area we need to find $=6+\frac{1}{2}\cdot (8-h) \cdot m$ and I managed to find that $h=4$ by the equation of straight line. So the area would be $=6+2m$.

But the given answer in the book is $6m-6$. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requisite area is that of the large right-angled triangle ($\frac12\cdot2m\cdot8=8m$) minus that of the small right-angled triangle ($\frac12(8-h)m$) minus the area under $g(x)$ ($6$).

Since the two right-angled triangles share an angle they are similar; since one side of the large triangle ($2m$, the height) is twice that of the corresponding side of the small triangle, the former has four times the area of the latter and the requisite area is thus $8m-2m-6=6m-6$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the area sought after is the area of the large triangle minus the area of the small triangle minus $\int_0^h g(x) dx =6$. Thus

$$Area = \frac12(8)(2m) - \frac12 (4)(m) - 6 = 6m - 6
$$